# How to double these numbers in an array using recursion, rest/spread operators and destructuring?

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I recently completed a JavaScript challenge asking to return a new array with all the values of the initial array doubled.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function double() {

}
```

Except that I was to include some ES6 topics of de-structuring and rest/spread operators as well as recursion. Well, I completed as best as I could to come to a solution. This was my solution:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function double(arr){
 const doubledNumbers = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
  const dubba = arr[i];
  const bubba = dubba * 2;
   doubledNumbers.push(bubba);
 }
 return doubledNumbers;

}
```

**The other requirement was to not use any array helper method (map, reduce etc)**, so I did not use `map()`, but instead a `for` loop. However, I could not wrap my head around implementing de-structuring or rest/spread operators, concepts I thought I knew pretty well, never-mind recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation - destructure the parameter of `double`, taking out the first number in the array, and use rest syntax to put the rest of the numbers into another array. Then, `double` the rest of the array, and spread it into a new (returned) array, headed by the first number times 2:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

function double([firstNum, ...rest]) {
  const restDoubled = rest.length ? double(rest) : [];
  return [firstNum * 2, ...restDoubled];
}

console.log(double(numbers));
```

Comment: This was the only exact (minimal) syntax I could get the function working without using array helper functions, push(), or using even more obscure versions that use Symbol and other alternatives described below by Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few alternatives -

```js
const None =
  Symbol("None")

const double = ([ x = None, ...more ]) =>
  x === None
    ? []
    : [ x * 2, ...double(more) ]

console.log(double([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]))
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Without destructuring -

```js
const double = (nums = [], i = 0) =>
  i >= nums.length
    ? []
    : [ nums[i] * 2, ...double(nums, i + 1) ]

console.log(double([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]))
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Using higher-order functions (functions that accept or return other functions) -

```js
const None =
  Symbol("None")

const identity = x =>
  x

const map = ([ x = None, ...more ], f = identity) =>
  x === None
    ? []
    : [ f(x), ...map(more, f) ]
    
const double = (nums = []) =>
  map(nums, n => n * 2)
  
console.log(double([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]))
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Using continuation passing style -

```js
const None =
  Symbol("None")

const identity = x =>
  x

const double = ([ x = None, ...more ], then = identity) =>
  x === None
    ? then([])
    : double(more, r => then([ x * 2, ...r ]))
  
double([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], console.log)
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to use recursion when we can do this using simple code as below

```
numbers = numbers.map(x => 2*x)
```

Comment: "The other requirement was to not use any array helper method"

Comment: Do you think 2x will work in js? It's not just normal math as we do in school time. You'll need to use multiply symbol. `2*x`. Though, from the OP, not to use array helper to complete the challenge.

Comment: Though, its not the case that OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is below -

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let finalResults = [];

function double(numbers) {    
   const [ number, ...rest ] = numbers;
   if(number === undefined) {
      return finalResults;
   } else {
      finalResults.push(number*2);
      return double([...rest]);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A another way:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const arr = [];
function double([x, ...some]) {
    arr.push(x*2);
    if(!some.length)
        return arr;
   return double(some);

}
```

`double(1,2,3)` will return `double(2,3)` which in turn will return `double(3)` and finally `double(3)` is going to return array `[2,4,6]`